# Can Enterprise Architect connect to adb debugger to generate diagram sequence?

Tags: android, sequence-diagram

I found interesting information on [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/the_android_debugger.html) which was speaking about connecting to any anylzer scripts for android adb. I tried to use

```
adb forward tcp:<adb port> jwdp:<pid running application>
```

but i still gets

> error: cannot bind to socket

or

```
error: internal error
```

Is is even possible to generate live diagram sequence from running app ? If EA is not able to do it, what app would be abble archieve this?

Comment: "•adb forward tcp:port jdwp:pid
 •port = port number listed in analyzer script"

 Can you check what port is set in your analyzer script? Also make sure that port isn't used already.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try getting the jwdp working on local machine, and then with EA from remote machine (i assume this is your goal as pointed in that link).

in your command there is an error. It is not `<adb port>` , it is any **ununsed** local port. So the command would be

```
adb forward tcp:<unused local port> jwdp:<pid running application>
```

once you have this successfully executed, you can test local jdb analyzer with

```
`jdb -attach localhost:<above configured local port>`
```

And if this works, then i would either run EA locally, or if you would like to use EA on a remote machine then we need to "have a proxy running on the remote machine that listens to all incoming connections **from EA** and forwards all traffic to the **unused local port**, that you configured above". In the link you posted it says "adb port", but its actually the `forwarded port`.